# Why does form:label and form:input break application

Tags: java, forms, jsp

I am making an application that uses forms.

In order for the form data to be passed to a java class, I need to use form:label and form:input.

However, these break the application.  I tried changing it to label and input, and that seems to make it work.

However, if I leave it at that, the data will not be passed correctly to the Java class.  Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
< tr class="oe_form_group_row">
    < td class="oe_form_group_cell oe_form_group_cell_label">
        < form: label path="licensePlateExpiry"> License Plate Expiry
            < /form:label>
                < /td>
                    < td class="oe_form_group_cell">
                        < span class="oe_form_field oe_form_field_char">
                            < form: input path="licensePlateExpiry" maxlength="20">
                                < /form:input>
                                    </span>
                                    < /tr>
```

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: "break" ... what this mean, some errors, exceptions?

Comment: Some aspects of the page don't appear.  Namely, the form.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the bean did not have the necessary information to store the license plate expiry information.  I also forgot to build the bean file.

Who knew that JSP was so picky?

Thanks for the help everyone.